# JQUERY - toggle divs based on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large number of DIVs on a page. Each being a container for an Unordered List. Above each DIV is a header text which consists of an  element with an anchor.

e.g.

```
<h2><a id="header1" href="#" > Header 1 </a></h3>
<div id="container1">
 <ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2><a id="header2" href="#" > Header 2 </a></h3>
<div <div id="container2">>
 <ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to have all these DIVs hidden until the header (anchor) is clicked. If the user clicks header it should toggle show/hide DIV

How can I accomplish this in JQUERY in a way that I can have one onClick function for all the DIVS, possibly using an id to differentiate between divs?

```
<h2><a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv(container1)"> Header 1 </a></h3>

function toggleDiv(id) {

}
```

but in JQUERY ?

SOLVED!!!!

```
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('.toggle-link').on('click', function() {
   var linkId = $(this).attr('data-div-id');
$('#' + linkId).toggle();
 });
});
</script>

<h2><a href="#" class="toggle-link" data-div-id="div1"> Header 1 </a></h2>
<div id="div1">
 <ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2><a href="#" class="toggle-link" data-div-id="div2"> Header 2 </a></h2>
<div id="div2">
 <ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.toggle()` in jQuery

> toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected
>   elements.

```
function toggleDiv(id) {
  $('#'+id).toggle();   
}
```

where id is the parameter you pass

Comment: thanks, I finally did figure it out. I am updating my code above to reflect

Comment: @JakeSays Fine. Happy to help